# How is it possible to instantiate a ViewModel in a unit test?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, testing, viewmodel

The following codelab instantiates a `ViewModel` in a unit test without using Robolectric or any mock library.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-test-viewmodel

How is this possible? I thought that `ViewModel`, which is part of an Android library, would not run in the JVM.

Answer (score 4):

> How is this possible?

ViewModel is a Java class like any other. As such an instance of it can be instantiated like any other.

> I thought that ViewModel, which is part of an Android library, would not run in the JVM.

`ViewModel` is actually not "part of an Android library" - it is part of the `JetPack` [lifecycle component library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle). These are extensions to - but *not* part of - the core Android framework. You can see from [the ViewModel source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.java?q=file:androidx%2Flifecycle%2FViewModel.java%20class:androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel) that the base `ViewModel` class has no dependencies on core Android framework classes - just other `JetPack` classes and standard `Java` classes.

As such, you don't require the Android runtime to be present to use a `ViewModel` which means you can run it on the local unit test JVM.